# jQuery UI toggleClass method with options doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

According to [this jQuery UI documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-switch-options), there is a `toggleClass` method which takes an `options` object. However, looking in the source, I don't see this version of the method being supported. When I try to the following, no animation occurs:

```
$("#element").toggleClass("fixed", showOrHide, {
    duration: animationDuration,
    easing: "swing",
    queue: false,
    children: true
});
```

I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.11.0. Am I missing something here?

Please view [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HNrDT/) and [here is a version without Bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/HNrDT/2/) to show that it is not a conflict issue.

**Note:** `.addClass( className [, options ] )` does not work either!

**jQuery UI Snippet**

```
toggleClass: (function( orig ) {
    return function( classNames, force, speed, easing, callback ) {
        if ( typeof force === "boolean" || force === undefined ) {
            if ( !speed ) {
                // without speed parameter
                return orig.apply( this, arguments );
            } else {
                return $.effects.animateClass.call( this,
                    (force ? { add: classNames } : { remove: classNames }),
                    speed, easing, callback );
            }
        } else {
            // without force parameter
            return $.effects.animateClass.call( this,
                { toggle: classNames }, force, speed, easing );
        }
    };
})( $.fn.toggleClass )
```

Comment: are there any errors in the console?  Do you have jQuery UI imported?  What version of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.11.0. No errors, just nothing happens. And inspecting the jQuery UI js file, I don't see how the `options` version of the function would be supported at all. Code added to question.

Comment: $("#element").toggleClass( "fixed",{switch:showOrHide,duration:animationDuration, easing:"swing",queue: true}); this will work

Comment: Can you post the markup of the element whose class you want to toggle? Did you try specifying `children: true` in case the animation should also apply to some of its descendants?

Comment: Added jsFiddle links to the question.

Comment: @Josh, it kinda works (with some artefacts) when you remove `queue: false`. I guess animating transitions from and to fixed position is not jQuery UI's forte (yet).

Comment: I don't see any animation even after doing as you suggested.

Comment: It may depend on the browser. I can see an animation when going from fixed to static on Firefox 29 (but the animation looks wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    var animationDuration=1000;

        var t=true;

        function showOrHide()
        {
            if(t)
            t=false
            else
            t=true
            return t;
        }


   $("#element").toggleClass( "fixed",showOrHide(),{duration:animationDuration, easing:"swing",queue: true});


you can also use like this

  $("#element").toggleClass( "fixed",{switch:showOrHide,duration:animationDuration, easing:"swing",queue: true});
```

Comment: Your first example is no different than what I was already doing (and posted in the question). The second example does not honor the `switch` parameter.